# How to change the background color of the selected text from clear to black when contextMenu is active?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, menu, contextmenu

[image: Simulator]

#this is just an example of the code so when i longpress the "Text("Long press for menu")" and is showing the contextmenu to change the background color:

````
 struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
        Text("Long press for menu")
            .contextMenu {
                Button {
                    print("Pills selected")
                } label: {
                    Label("Pills", systemImage: "pills")
                }

                Button {
                    print("Heart selected")
                } label: {
                    Label("Heart rate", systemImage: "heart")
                }

                Button {
                    print("ECG selected")
                } label: {
                    Label("ECG", systemImage: "waveform.path.ecg")
                }
            }
    }
}```
````

Comment: So you just want it to show a completely black rectangle?

Comment: yes the background color of the text when is on Long Press Gesture and is showing the contextmenu, like the background of  rectangle to be in black and the text in white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the contextMnenu is creating a rectangle around the text, and this rectangle seems to hate transparency like Color.clear or opacity applied to white. As I've become accostumed to say "SwiftUI never cease to suprprise me (both in good and bad ways)". So you need to build your custom menu for that. You can get away with something like the following:

```
struct ContextMenuDetectOpenClose: View {

@State private var isContextMenuOpen = false
private let items: [Item] = [
    .init(title: "Pills", icon: "pills"),
    .init(title: "Heart rate", icon: "heart"),
    .init(title: "ECG", icon: "waveform.path.ecg")
]

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Text("Long press for menu")
            .padding(4)
            .background(isContextMenuOpen ? .gray : .clear, in: .rect(cornerRadius: 8))
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .background(.clear)
            .onLongPressGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    isContextMenuOpen = true
                }
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                if isContextMenuOpen {
                    MenuList()
                        .offset(y: 40)
                }
            }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.black)
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation {
            isContextMenuOpen = false
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
func MenuList() -> some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            
            HStack {
                Text(item.title)
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                Image(systemName: item.icon)
            }
            .font(.title3)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            .clipShape(.rect)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("On tap \(item.title)")
                withAnimation {
                    isContextMenuOpen = false
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    .frame(width: 250, height: 180)
    .background(.white.opacity(0.8), in: .rect(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let icon: String
}
```

}

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: thanks for the response @MatBuompy but i meant the background color of the text when is on Long Press Gesture and is showing the contextmenu, like the background of  rectangle to be in black and the text in white but in first view to be as it is in image.

Comment: You didn't say text white in the question. I can update the code if you want to, but it's easily achievable using the foregroundStyle modifier using the same logic as the background.

Comment: Anyway, if you found my answer useful, please, I would appreciate you if you at least upvoted since it took me time to figure out what the best solution could be.